# laravel insert data after few time later

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function index()
{
    $value="";
    $now = time();
    if ($now == '1568739550'){
        $dummy = new Dummy();
        $dummy->name = "khan";
        $dummy->save();
    }else{
        $value = "not okay";
    }
    return view('home', compact('now', 'value'));
}
```

It is working when i contain refresh browser. Otherwise it is not working

Comment: what are you trying to do ? and what is the time '1568739550' supposed to represent ?

Comment: You have it creating a new dummy class only when time is a specific time, so it's only going to run once, if it runs at all, considering you have to time it just right.

Comment: if you need it automatically may be used use either command or queue job,

Comment: 1568739550 is future time. when $now reach the future time  i want it automatically insert data.

Comment: Good luck with that. It's going to have to hit that second exactly, which is hard to do with a browser.

Comment: i have a  laravel project and i want to add something like facebook birthday event.  the loop will return back in one day.

Comment: Suppose table1 and table2.When the time is 12pm then table1 data transfered to table2.Is it possible ? And it will happen everyday at night 12pm just once.

Answer (score 0):

Carbon for this purpose like below..

```
// get the current time
$current = Carbon::now();
// add 30 days to the current time
$trialExpires = $current->addDay
```

And then simply call if function

```
 if(your condition)
{
//Login goes here
}
```

Comment: i have a  laravel project and i want to add something like facebook birthday event.  the loop will return back in one day.

Comment: Oh then you have create a table where users birthday will be store. And run a query wich will match the birthday date. And if the date is meet then user will see a notification...... If it is not your answer then describe the whole process what actually you want to do

Comment: Suppose table1 and table2.When the time is 12pm then table1 data transfered to table2.Is it possible ? And it will happen everyday at night 12pm just once.

Comment: No it is not possible, but you can do one thing, suppose when the user is submitted data to one table, insert the data at that same time in thesecond table as well. Now check the time of it is 12 pm or not if it is 12 pm then show the rows. If you cant und3then let me know i will post with codes now i am in outside.. Once i will return to thw home i will try to give you the code.